# Do Gitlab Personal Access Tokens grant permissions on repos you own, or all repos you have access to?

Tags: gitlab

In Gitlab I can create a Personal Access Token for `read_repository` and `write_repository` permissions. Does this token grant access to just my projects in my namespace, or all projects that I have access to?

> `read_repository`
> Grants read-only access to repositories on private projects using Git-over-HTTP or the Repository Files API.
>
> `write_repository`
> Grants read-write access to repositories on private projects using Git-over-HTTP (not using the API).